# How to redirect form using click here for submit?

Tags: javascript, php, forms, form-submit

anyone can help i have a form, i want do something like this : 
http://criminalcase.ha-lab.com/

there is a boutom "Click Here Before Submit", when you click on it you are redirected to the same page(*url dont change), and you can see the bottom submit (*no click here for submit). Thank you in advance for any help ^^

```
<form method="get" action="?">
 id : <input name="id" / size="45"/><br>
 Sig : <input name="sig" <br> 

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="==>click here befor submit<==" id="submit" />

</form>
```

what i want is when i click on click here befor submit it will redirect me to to do same page but with boutom submit

Comment: please show some piece of code then it is easy to understand

Comment: Why need to redirect. Just hide link and show button.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? It's really difficult understand you without code.

```js
$("#showSubmit").click(function(){
  $(this).hide();
  $("#submitButton").show();
})
```

```css
.hidden{ display:none}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <label>input</label><input type="text"/>
  <input type="submit" class="hidden" id="submitButton" value="submit" />
  <a href="#" id="showSubmit">Click here before submit</a>
</form>
```

Comment: sorry im just newbie ^^ i just updat and sent code, the best exemple is the website, you must click on click here befor sumbit to see submit
thank you very much

Comment: something like this but want use redirection shortlink, like the guy did !! if it' possible ! the website i sent you must click on "click here befor submit" after you are redirected (page is refreshed) then you can see submit like you did, and the url of the website dont change

Comment: So, you want a link instead of a button? I have edited the code again.

Comment: thanksyou, yes a link, the problem with your code is i can't use shortlink with click here before submite like the other guy did

see code source : http://criminalcase.ha-lab.com/ and search for click here befor submit

there is another exemple :http://old-skys.net/cc/ and this guy did it i think with php it auto redirected to a page named complete.php and this page redirect you to your page php with form with submit

Comment: I think that the link has to redirect you to a php script, create a $_SESSION with the form's data and redirect with header("location: advertisementPage.php"), show the advertisement. generate the button after the countdown, and with that button come back to form and fill the form's data with the $_SESSION variables cretaed in your script and show de submit button after checking if the $_SESSION variables exist. It's easy, but you need to have knowledges of PHP or another server-side languages .

Comment: thank you very much, for all fast answer yep it will help me alot  ^^ so now i can search more about " create a $_SESSION with the form's data and redirect with header" thank you again ^^

Answer (score 0):

I am also trying to understand What Dr House is asking, I would like to slightly modify what JuaRoAI has done, and do something like this, try it and let us know:

```js
$("#showSubmit").click(function(){
  $(this).hide();
  $("#submitButton").show();
})
```

```css
.hidden{ display:none}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <label>input</label><input type="text"/>
  <input type="submit" class="hidden" id="submitButton" value="submit" />
  <a href="" id="showSubmit">Click here before submit</a>
</form>
```